# Does @required and @validate decorators make sense at production?

Tags: angular, typescript

At my current project, I found that `@required` and `@validate` decorators are used everywhere. Their realizations are taken from here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators
just AS IS.

```
import "reflect-metadata";
const requiredMetadataKey = Symbol("required");
 
function required(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, parameterIndex: number) {
  let existingRequiredParameters: number[] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(requiredMetadataKey, target, propertyKey) || [];
  existingRequiredParameters.push(parameterIndex);
  Reflect.defineMetadata( requiredMetadataKey, existingRequiredParameters, target, propertyKey);
}
 
function validate(target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Function>) {
  let method = descriptor.value!;
 
  descriptor.value = function () {
    let requiredParameters: number[] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(requiredMetadataKey, target, propertyName);
    if (requiredParameters) {
      for (let parameterIndex of requiredParameters) {
        if (parameterIndex >= arguments.length || arguments[parameterIndex] === undefined) {
          throw new Error("Missing required argument.");
        }
      }
    }
    return method.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

Example of code

```
  @validate
  print(@required verbose: boolean) {
    if (verbose) {
      return `type: ${this.type}\ntitle: ${this.title}`;
    } else {
     return this.title; 
    }
  }
```

The main idea of it: These decorators work at runtime and if this function will be fired without the required param it WILL NOT be invoked. Just error at console with text `Missing required argument.`

Fire method without params in our code we can't otherwise typescript can't build code and shows us errors. If it happens in production build it means we skipped the error somewhere above, not in validated function.

I haven't managed to find any examples of these on google.

My question:
Does it make sense? Is there a real profit from these decorators?

Comment: If you are using typescript, I don't see the point, because if you forget an argument you will just get a compiler error and don't even make it to runtime. That is, unless the codebase is full of `any` and the like, then good luck.

Comment: they are not required - it makes the code almost unusable for the exact reason the Clashsoft stated in their comment.

Comment: It is mostly useful for creating libraries that might not be used with typescript. If all your code uses typescript and you don't provide the result as a library to be used with plain js, then it unnecessarily bloats your code. That is for the required validation only. If you have other validation that typescript can't do, like min-max for a number, then it becomes very useful again

Comment: @x4rf41, could you write your comment as the answer? I will mark it as right